# How to activate button if a value is less than zero?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

On MS Access 2016, I have a button with property "not visible".

I want that button stay visible if a value in another field ([Balance]) is less than "0" (zero).

e.g. Balance is -5,00,  the button (btOpenReport) will appear visible.
     Balance is 1,00, the button (btOpenReport) is not visible

This code is not working, the button stay visible in all records, even the value is bigger than 0.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
'button invisible, ok
Me.btOpenReport.Visible = False
'must evaluate if Balance is less than 0 and put button visible,...not working 
If Me.Balance < 0 Then Me.btOpenReport.Visible = True
End Sub
```

What is wrong?

[Here is a db example (Ms Access 2016 Database1)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e4d1uzw62e0ldr/Database1.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a button visibility to be different on different records on a continuous form. It's simply not possible.

They only ways to achieve something similar is to either use a text box and some clever conditional formatting, to give the impression of a button that can be pressed or not, or better IMHO put the button in the form header or footer and enable/disable it via the On_current event.

Comment: Hi. Could I use this text box with the a visible caption "Open Report" only if the Balance was less than zero? So I could click on this text box as if it were a "Open Report" button. Right? 

Right now I added an example database to my first post/Question.

Comment: If you add a calculated field to your forms underlying query, call it {txtReport: IIf(Balance <0 ,"Open Report","")} .Then you can populate that on your form. 
On the on click property of the text box simply check the value isn't "" before carrying out the code you want to run, in case someone decides to press it even though it won't "appear" to be active.

Comment: It works.
    
To explain in a simple way:
1- In the query (grouped) I created a calculated field "txtRep";
    -If "Balance" is less than zero; "Open report"; "";
    -Total: expression.
2 - In the form, In the event of the new "txtRep";
    - in the macro to open the report I added at the beginning: If "txtRep" is  null Cancel; Else, the "open report" macro continues.

Answer (score 1):

You picked the wrong event. The Form_Current does not fire when you change a value in a textbox. See the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193159.aspx

Comment: Why not `Me.btOpenReport.Visible=Me.Balance <0`

Comment: @Fionnuala, thanks. It does not work. The button is visible in all records.

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant This is a continuous form, based on a grouping query. There is no text box to fill in or change. The "Balance" field is a sum.

Comment: I removed my recommendation but my answer still answers your question: You picked the wrong event.

Comment: A continuous form will drive you mad if you try to use events for an unbound control. This needs a query.